# Weblogic Server, Timed out waiting for completion, while creating a new server

Tags: weblogic, windows-7-x64, weblogic12c

I have installed the **Weblogic 12c (12.1.3)** on my Windows 7 machine. After creating the Admin server and logging in, I am trying to create a new Managed Server. But when I press the create button, it takes a lot of time showing the loading symbol and finally gives the error ***Timed out waiting for completion: Activate State: STATE_DISTRIBUTED Target Servers States: AdminServer STATE_DISTRIBUTED***. 
Earlier I was working on weblogic 10.3.2 and it was working fine, but after this installation it gives me the error and I am unable to create a new Managed Server.

My **JAVA_HOME is pointing to JDK 1.8** currently. Also there is this entry in the **PATH** variable which is something like ***'C:\ProgramData\Oracle\java\javapath'*** which has 3 SYMLINKS to java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe to my **JRE 1.8 instead of the JDK 1.8**. I uninstalled the JRE and just kept the JDK for the time being but still did not work.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to find the solution for it. Pointed my **JAVA_HOME** back to JDK 1.7 and at the same time changed the port of **NodeManager** from the default 5556 to 5557 and was able to successfully create and link the Machine and the Managed Server.